# Replacing url data with file data in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, api

I have a link which contains a field for id. I want to fill this field data with data from a csv/txt file. The link is going to help me get data for a particular api.The url looks something like this:
`https://xyz-vbjjdnj.com/api/version/collector/$JOB_ID$/results`

The `$job_id$` needs to be replaced with ids from my text file. How can I do it?
And the results needs to be saved further. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can read data from the CSV file using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

   For example if you have `test.csv` file which looks like:

   ```
   123
   456
   789
   ```

   You can configure the CSV Data Set Config like:

   [image]
2. Once done just use `${JOB_ID}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference in the URL like:

   ```
   https://xyz-vbjjdnj.com/api/version/collector/${JOB_ID}/results
   ```
3. If you want to store the result into a JMeter Variable add a [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) with empty left and right boundaries

   [image]

---

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Could you share your http request page ss ?

Comment: It's not a HTTP Request, it's a [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) with a fake response data of `result for ID: ${JOB_ID}`